# Can't get a the id in a ManyToOne element from TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am getting crazy with this issue. I have a ManyToOne Column in a Entity, and I need to get the id (that is the value saved in the table), but If I get the var in twig it takes the name that I have linked to show in the Entity -what expected- but how can I access to the id?

```
{{profile.CarOneId}}
//it gets `BMW 320`

{{dump(profile.CarOneId)}}
    Car {#2458 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      +id: 49
      +name: "BMW 320"
      +slug: "bmw-320"
      +native: true
      +perfil: PersistentCollection {#2604 ▶}
       …4
    }
```

I need to get the id, so take the "49" number.

The Car entity has the vars as public:

```
class Car
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
public $id;

/** @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100) */
public $name;

/** @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=100) */
public $slug;

/** @ORM\Column(name="native", type="boolean", nullable=true) */
public $native;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="car")
*/
public $profile;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->profile = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
* Get id
*
* @return integer
*/
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include your `Profile` entity along with the getter method you've shown? Also, if `profile.CarOneId` is returning an object of `Car` did you try something like `profile.CarOneId.id`?

Comment: /**
     * @ var integer
     *
     * @ ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Car", inversedBy="car")
     * @ ORM\JoinColumn(name="car_one_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    public $profileCarOneId;

    /**
     * Get profileCarOneId
     *
     * @ return integer
     */
    public function getProfileCarOneId()
    {
        return $this->profileCarOneId;
    }

Comment: note: I added spaces between @ and text intencionally to could publish here.

Comment: Did you tried accessing the `id` attribute as I've suggested at the end of my first comment?

Comment: @Artamiel: yes, I did. I get the message I'm trying to access a NULL value.